# obtain a number by addition or subtraction of consecutive natural numbers

Tags: java, c++, c, algorithm, math

I am trying to write a function using which I can obtain any natural number in minimum steps. Where I am allowed to add or subtract natural numbers starting from 1.
There the conditions are :

1. Use a number only once
2. You are allowed to perform only addition and subtraction.
3. You are not allowed to escape any digit
4. Find the value of the integer which has a maximum value to obtain that number.

**eg** : If I my desired number is 4 then it is obtained as -1+2+**3** here **answer is 3**. In a similar manner if I want 6 then 1+2+**3** here **answer is 3**. For **10**= 1+2+3+**4** ans is **4**.
what I have so far :

What I have so far:

```
public void step() { 
    int n = (int)Math.sqrt(position * 2); 
    k = (position - (((n + 1) * n) / 2)); 
    l = ((((n + 1) * (n + 2)) / 2) - position); 
    System.out.println(k + " " + l); 
    System.out.println(n); 
    p = (l > k ? k : l); 
    r = (l > k ? n : n + 1); 
    System.out.println(p + " " + r); 
    if (k == 0) { 
        result = n; 
    } else { 
        result = r + (2 * p); 
    } System.out.println("__________" + result + "__________"); 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: hmmm what kind of homework is this!

Comment: We'll help you with specific programming problems, but you need to go write a procedure for solving the logic problem yourself.

Comment: yes my code is `public void step() {
        int n = (int)Math.sqrt(position * 2);
        k = (position - (((n + 1) * n) / 2));
        l = ((((n + 1) * (n + 2)) / 2) - position);
        System.out.println(k + " " + l);
        System.out.println(n);
        p = (l > k ? k : l);
        r = (l > k ? n : n + 1);
        System.out.println(p + " " + r);
        if (k == 0) {
            result = n;
        } else {
        result = r + (2 * p);
        }
        System.out.println("__________" + result + "__________");
    }` but this is not proper it needs some recursive function I guess.

Comment: If you can only use numbers starting from 1 how come in the first example you used -1?

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have so far :)

Comment: Sum until you surpass the absolute value of what you want to get. If you surpassed the target value by an even number, flip the sign for the addend that will correct the sum to the desired value. Otherwise, add one or two more numbers such that the sum surpasses the desired value by an even number, then flip the correct sign.

Comment: @Kamal_prd [Edit your question and include your code](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18308139/edit). Psst! Fast!

Comment: @Joni here I mentions addition or subtraction, so it could take +1 as well as -1.

Comment: The number 1 is the first in the list; it's not added to anything or subtracted from anything. With the given rules you can't replace 1 with -1.

Comment: Ok let me clarify further, the number can be achieved by using +ve or negative value of continuous natural numbers, starting from 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The solution is :

```
for n=1: = 1
for n=2: = 1+2 => 1+2+3 => 1-2+3 
for n=3: = 1+2
for n=4: = 1+2+3 => -1+2+3
for n=5: = 1+2+3 => 1+2+3+4-5
for n=6: = 1+2+3
for n=7: = 1+2+3+4=>1+2+3+4+5=>1+2+3-4+5
for any n, first calculate the S(k)=1+2+3+...+k
```

where S(k)>n and x=S(k)-n is an even number. Then go flip the + of x/2 to -.

```
S(k) = (1+k)*k/2 > n
=> k*k + k -2n > 0
=> k > (-1 + sqrt(1+8n))/2
```

eg, n=7, k > 3.2, then k=4, S(4) = 10, 10-7=3, it's odd, so k=5, S(5)=15, x=15-7=8, 8/2=4, flip the sign of 4, we got 1+2+3-4+5 = 7

in some cases, Sk-n is odd, but S(k+1)-n is also odd, in this case, we need to use S(k+2).
The code is as follow :

```
public void step() {
        k = (int)Math.ceil(((-1 + Math.sqrt(1 + 8 * n)) / 2));
        int Sk = (1 + k) * k / 2;
        if ((Sk - n) % 2 != 0) {
            k++;
            Sk = (1 + k) * k / 2;
            if ((Sk - n) % 2 != 0) {
                k++;
                Sk = (1 + k) * k / 2;
            }
        }
        int i = (Sk - n) / 2;
        System.out.println("maximum number is : " + k + "the number with -ve sign is : " + i);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, lets do it in this way. Consider following `binary tree`. now you can find sum from each path and take every path with `sum=your number(let's say 4)`. now you can get the maximum value from those. Try to come up with implementation of this. I can help you further, If you try some thing.

```
      0
     /  \
    -1   1
   /  \  / \
  -2  2 -2  2
```